# Run script and php after form submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have an html form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="save.php">
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in save.php i have something like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$email_content = "Thank you for your subscription";
mail($email,"Thank you",$email_content);
header("Location:thankyou.php");
?>
```

Now in save.php file i need to send this e-mail but also to echo a script that runs a js function. For example

```
<?php
    echo "<script>";
    echo "<script src='my_path_to_file/file.js'></script>";
    echo "var subscriberEmail = '" . $email . "';";
    echo "mySubscribe(subscriberEmail);";
    echo "</script>";
 ?>
```

Now, if i place the echoing of the script before mail(), then i don't go to thankyou.php, mail() is not executed, i don't go to thankyou.php but script function works. If i place echoing of script after mail, then mail is sent, i go to thankyou.php but script function is not executed at all.

Any ideas to make both happen?

Thank you in advance

Comment: (1) The HTML `<script>` elements you're trying to echo are invalid.  (2) You either echo output to the page *or* you redirect to a different page.  Not both.  You have to choose which one you want to do.  Do you want to echo this script ***or*** do you want to redirect to the "thank you" page?  (Maybe just put this script *on* the "thank you" page?)

Comment: why don't you use ajax to send the form content (as JSON) to the php file, and then do whatever script you want on the done function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becouse echo command send content to browser, and header redirect will never works.

You could try to use comething like that:

```
<?php
echo "<script>";
echo "<script src='my_path_to_file/file.js'></script>";
echo "var subscriberEmail = '" . $email . "';";
echo "mySubscribe(subscriberEmail);";
echo "document.location.href='thankyou.php';";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

It means, move redirect command from php code to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly some error in mySubscribe(subscriberEmail); function. Thats is why if you put script before email and header("Location:thankyou.php");  it not sending mail and redirects you. And also if you put script before,  $email variable is not set yet